# designing for failure when polling/retrying/queueing is not possible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb

I'm designing a website/web service to be hosted in the cloud (specifically AWS although that's mostly irrelevant), and I'm spending a lot of time thinking about "designing for failure". I want my system to seamlessly handle node failures, i.e. without any significant user impact or engineer intervention.

In most cases, it's easy to see how to handle sudden node failure. If my app has an API handled by 4 servers behind a load balancer, polled by AJAX or an iPhone app, the poller can simply detect the failed TCP/IP transmission and retry... assuming the load balancer behaves correctly, it will hit a healthy instance.

If the app is more processing-oriented, a queue service like SQS can be used to allow stateless nodes to pick up where the failed nodes left off.

The difficulty I see is with "points of entry", where no retry/polling is possible because the application hasn't been loaded yet, and where a failure means the app never starts. For example, the index.html on a webpage... if a node fails while transmitting that file, the user's browser will likely hang and not automatically retry (they will need to refresh).

The Load Balancer is also a single "point of entry/failure". However, in this case it appears we can solve the problem by creating multiple Load Balancers, and load balancing *them* using DNS Load Balancing as described here: http://blog.rightscale.com/2012/10/23/dns-load-balancing-and-using-multiple-load-balancers-in-the-cloud/

Is this a solution that would work for the simpler index.html case? Overall, how can we create redundancy where polling/retrying/queuing is not possible?

EDIT: Another idea is to have the index.html hosted statically on a CDN, S3, etc (where resource availability is more dependable), although that prevents using dynamic content. Dynamic content could be added if the page populates itself using JS, but that adds a dependency on JS as well as latency for the user.